# C# equivalent of PHP str_replace for variant using arrays as strings to replace?

Tags: c#

What is C#/.Net equivalent of PHP `str_replace` method that takes two arrays [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

> ```
> str_replace(
>    array|string $search,
>    array|string $replace,
>    string|array $subject,
>    int &$count = null
> ): string|array
> ```
>
> If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values.

I want to migrate PHP code to C# code and I can't replace like this statement :

```
$e_s=array('\\','\'','"','select','drop','delete');
$d_s=array('','','','removed','removed','removed');
```

```
$text = str_replace( $e_s, $d_s, $text );
```

```
string[] e_s = new string[] { "\\", "\'", "select", "drop", "delete"};
string[] d_s = new string[] { "", "", "removed", "removed", "removed" };
```

I looked at [`String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) but there is no override taking arrays. Is there a better way than manually iterating arrays and using `string.Replace` on each pair (I've seen some people saying that repeatedly calling `Replace` is a bad practice).

Comment: can you show n example? what are you expecting and what is the actual outout, its not clear in your question

Comment: Please remove the php tag from the question. The task involved will have no part that will require php coding.

Comment: @Mashtan Yes, but `str_replace` in PHP works fundamentally differently to a simple text replacement in .NET. Knowing that the bizarre `$e_s=array(` syntax is PHP allows us non-PHP developers to look up the PHP documentation and understand how `str_replace` works in PHP so that we can advise of a solution in .NET. Normally I would be against tagging multiple languages, but for questions that are essentially "what is the equivalent of this code in this language because my attempt isn't working?", it's actually useful.

Comment: Instead of assuming that C# will work exactly the same way PHP works, why don't you take the time to actually find out how C# works? You seem to think that we will provide some magic solution to allow you to do it the way you want, instead of you working out how you actually need to do it. Did you, for instance, read the documentation for the `String.Replace` method? We can help with the stuff you can't work out but you have to actually try first.

Comment: Now after my edit t is "clear" that OP read both set of docs, it's time to unleash Aggregate and other LINQ monstrosities :)